# How to convert an array-like string to an array in spark-dataframe (Scala api)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following spark dataframe:

```
published   data
2019-05-15T10:37:22+00:00   [{"@id":"1","@type":"type","category":"cat"},{"@id":"2","@type":"type","category":"cat1"}]
```

with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- published: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: string (nullable = true)
```

The second column "data" is not an array but an array-like string.

Is there a way to gracefully convert such a string into a sequence object so I could explode different @ids into separate rows?

Thank you!

P.S. Code for df creation:

```
val df = Seq(("2019-05-15T10:37:22+00:00", """[{"@id":"1","@type":"type","category":"cat"},{"@id":"2","@type":"type","category":"cat1"}]""")).toDF("published", "data")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `from_json`:

```
val df = Seq(("2019-05-15T10:37:22+00:00", """[{"@id":"1","@type":"type","category":"cat"},{"@id":"2","@type":"type","category":"cat1"}]"""))
  .toDF("published", "data")

val schema = ArrayType(StructType(Array(StructField("@id", StringType))))
df.select($"published", from_json($"data", schema) as "ids")
  .select($"published", explode($"ids.@id") as "id")
  .show(20, false)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+---+
|published                |id |
+-------------------------+---+
|2019-05-15T10:37:22+00:00|1  |
|2019-05-15T10:37:22+00:00|2  |
+-------------------------+---+
```

Answer (score 3):

With recent versions of Spark (since 2.3.0), you can also use [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@from_json(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema:String,options:Map[String,String]):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) with schema specified as a DDL string (this used to be a Java-only API):

```
val schema = "array<map<`@id`: string, `@type`: string, category: string>>"

df.select($"published", from_json($"data", schema, Map.empty[String,String]) as "data")
  .select($"published", explode($"data") as "data")
  .select($"published", $"data.@id", $"data.category")
  .show(false)
```

```
+-------------------------+---+--------+
|published                |@id|category|
+-------------------------+---+--------+
|2019-05-15T10:37:22+00:00|1  |cat     |
|2019-05-15T10:37:22+00:00|2  |cat1    |
+-------------------------+---+--------+
```

The map argument specifies parsing options from among the ones understood by that the JSON `DataFrame` reader.